# Conflict in deleting because of some digits

Tags: list-manipulation

I  have a list at [3dplot](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=59424717141645344725) and I want to have a list the second element of which be equal to `0.2`

```
sELECTdplot= Select[3dplot, (#[[2]] == 0.20 &)]
(***
 {{0., 0.2, -0.0793037}, {0.2, 0.2, -0.0903679}, {0.4, 
 0.2, -0.100867}, {0.6, 0.2, -0.111708}, {0.8, 0.2, -0.123335}, {1., 
 0.2, -0.135819}, {1.2, 0.2, -0.148896}, {1.4, 0.2, -0.162047}, {1.6,
 0.2, -0.174654}, {1.8, 0.2, -0.186165}, {2., 0.2, -0.196225}}
 **)
```

and after that I want to delete the second element of any sublist (removing 0.2 from all elements) for this reason I have used of

```
dELETTED= DeleteCases[sELECTdplot, 0.2, Infinity]
(***{{0., 0.2, -0.0793037}, {0.2, -0.0903679}, {0.4, 
 0.2, -0.100867}, {0.6, 0.2, -0.111708}, {0.8, 0.2, -0.123335}, {1., 
 0.2, -0.135819}, {1.2, 0.2, -0.148896}, {1.4, 0.2, -0.162047}, {1.6,
 0.2, -0.174654}, {1.8, 0.2, -0.186165}, {2., 0.2, -0.196225}}**)
```

Deleting just happened for `{0.2, -0.0903679}` the second element. it is because of when I copy one of `0.2`s in the sELECTdplot they are originally are `0.20000000000000004`. How can I get rid of this annoying case?! Also I cannot understand why must we use of `Infinity` in the `DeleteCases`. Without this we cannot reach to a desired result.

Comment: The `Infinity` is necessary because `DeleteCases` operates on `Level` 1, by default (i.e. it's checking to see if each of the lists is equal to `0.2`, which clearly isn't the case). You could also do `DeleteCases[sELECTdplot, 0.2, {2}]`, because the third argument forces `DeleteCases` to look at the quantities at `Level` 2, which are all of the numbers in the 3-element lists.

Comment: @Ackaran - I don't understand how you have defined a variable as `3dplot`?  In your data file you have `3dplot = ......` which of course gives an error because variables can't begin with numbers.

Comment: I understood this error, I could not remove that

Comment: `3dplot`will be interpreted as 3*dplot. As stated by @JasonB, you can simply remove the second column, without any need for matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use `DeleteCases` here, you can use `Part` to remove the middle column.

```
Select[dplot, (#[[2]] == 0.20 &)][[All, {1, 3}]]
(* {{0., -0.0793037}, {0.2, -0.0903679}, {0.4, -0.100867}, 
{0.6, -0.111708}, {0.8, -0.123335}, {1., -0.135819}, {1.2, 
-0.148896}, {1.4, -0.162047}, {1.6, -0.174654}, {1.8, -0.186165}, 
{2., -0.196225}} *)
```